# How do I invert the order of a variable in a tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have some fantasy football data from my league. 12 teams x 8 years = 96 observations. I'm trying to create `tibble(year, team, record)`. The `team` and `record` variables are organized correctly. But my `year` column is in the wrong order. It's current order is below, but I need to reverse it so that 2019 starts at the top and 2012 is the last observation. Each value in the `year` column repeats 12 times since there are 12 teams. There are no NA values. Thanks in advance.

```
year   team   record
2012
2012
2012
2012
2012
2012
2012
2012
2012
2012
2012
2012
2013
2013
2013
.
.
.
2019
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb, this was quite easy. I'll leave it for others and I'll accept any other answer that works. I just inverted year numerically. `year <- year[96:1]` then did `tibble(year, team, record)`

Comment: try `order` or `sort` which will help you doing things dynamically and without the need of hardcoding